# How to prevent spring realods its context in tests

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I have a problem running my tests, because in a certain moment, the spring reloads the context, searching the config-server settings again, i noticed that it always reloads after the second message:

```
2017-08-13 15:05:54.411  INFO [payment,,,] 3360 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@76c548f: startup date [Sun Aug 13 15:05:54 BRT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-13 15:05:54.681  INFO [payment,,,] 3360 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$719706d0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

During the execution of my 40 tests this message appears 4 times, making the spring reload the context 4 times as well. I'm using Spring Cloud ecosystem (Config, Hystrix) does anyone know what it can be?

In fact, i would also like to know what causes spring reloads the context

Note: im not using @DirtiesContext

Comment: well, what are you using then? can you provide a test case showing the behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

i found the problem, it's the use of @ MockBean, it forces the spring to reload the context in each class that it is used. That's the tip.

Comment: I removed all the @MockBeans from my tests. And I still see the context being reloaded. But it doesn't happen all the time, just for certain tests. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My tests always extend to the PaymentApplicationTests class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = PaymentApplication.class, 
    properties = { "spring.cloud.config.enabled:true", "management.security.enabled=false"})
@RabbitListenerTest
@Transactional
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public abstract class PaymentApplicationTests {

    public static final String JSON_MEDIA_TYPE = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";

    @Autowired
    protected EntityManager em;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;

    @SpyBean
    protected DomainEventPublisher domainEventPublisher;

    @Autowired
    public RabbitListenerTestHarness harness;

    public static EmbeddedAMQPBroker broker;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void startBroker() throws Exception {
        if (broker == null) {
            broker = new EmbeddedAMQPBroker();
            int port = broker.port();
            System.setProperty("spring.rabbitmq.port", String.valueOf(port));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an abstract class something like this:

```
package <package>;

import com.realty.project.AbstractTestController;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:/application-test.properties")
public abstract class AbstractTestApplication {
}
```

Inherit this class in your test classes, this stops creating of context in each test class. The reason this ensures no reloading of your spring context is that the same context is shared across all the test classes. If you have annotation @SpringBootTest on top of each class, spring has to re-create the context again and again.

Bit more context is explained here: http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2010/12/speeding-up-spring-integration-tests.html